# Using define_method in a loop to create methods in Ruby (Through Selenium Webdriver)

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver

I'm trying to create a method to dynamically do the following: (as I will have to implement this on about 30 different sets of sub-classes)

```
  def t1
    FooT1.new
  end

  def t2
    FooT2.new
  end

  def t3
    FooT3.new
  end
```

Where there will be 2 variables in the method generation, the tab number(t1...tx) and the name of the class (Foo)

I tried the following, but I'm new to Ruby and can not get this working.

```
def method_generator(num_tabs, class_name)
  1.upto(num_tabs) do |i|
    define_method("t#{i}") do
      "#{class_name}_t#{i}".new
    end
  end
end
```

Then call it in the sub-class like so:

```
method_generator(3, "Bar")
```

I'm aware I'm probably quite far off in implementing this, so any help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you give more information about what error you get?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do as below :

```
def method_generator(num_tabs, class_name)
  1.upto(num_tabs) do |i|
    class_name.send(:define_method,"t#{i}") do
      "#{class_name}_t#{i}".new
    end
  end
end
```

[`Module#define_method`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Module.html#method-i-define_method) is a **private method**, thus you can't call it on the `class_name` like `class_name.define_method(:name) do ..end`, as private method call not allows explicit receiver. But to do so [`Object#send`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Object.html#method-i-send) will help you, as this method is here for this kind of scenarios, where you can't call private method by explicit receiver.

Lets verify with an example, if this tricks works or not.

```
class Foo;end

def method_generator(num_tabs, class_name)
  1.upto(num_tabs) do |i|
    class_name.send(:define_method,"t#{i}") do
      "#{class_name}_t#{i}".new
    end
  end
end

method_generator(3,Foo)
Foo.instance_methods(false)
# => [:t1, :t2, :t3] # see here 3 instance methods has been created of class Foo
```

Comment: Thanks, I had to change it slightly to get it work in my framework, Object.const_get("#{class_name}_t#{i}").new, but other than that worked great